# input cursor is not staying where it is placed it is going again at the last of input text

Tags: html, reactjs

here is the code:

```
 const [expression, setExpression] = useState("");

 const Remove = () => {        
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    if (expression.length > 0) {
        const pos = input.selectionStart;
        if (pos > 0) {
     setExpression(expression.substring(0, pos - 1) + expression.substring(pos));
          input.focus();
          input.selectionStart = pos - 1;
          input.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
        }
      }
}

return (
<>
<input id="input" value={expression} />
<button onClick={Remove}>remove</button>
</>
)
```

I want to remove the text where cursor is place in input box on button click but the cursor goes again and again at the end of input text after removing the number. I want it to stay where it is placed in input field and not go at the end of input box text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a *stateful* and *stateless* way.

**Stateful**

```js
  const [expression, setExpression] = useState("");
  const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
  }, [cursorPos, expression]);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setExpression(e.target.value);
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    setCursorPos(input.selectionStart);
  }

  const Remove = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    if (expression.length > 0) {
      const pos = input.selectionStart;
      if (pos > 0) {
        setExpression(
          expression.substring(0, pos - 1) + expression.substring(pos)
        );
        setCursorPos(pos - 1);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input id="input" value={expression} onInput={handleInput} />
      <button onClick={Remove}>remove</button>
    </>
  );
```

**Stateless**, using ref

```js
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const Remove = () => {
    const input = inputRef.current;
    const value = input.value;
    if (value.length > 0) {
      const pos = input.selectionStart;
      if (pos > 0) {
        input.value = value.substring(0, pos - 1) + value.substring(pos);
        input.focus();
        input.selectionStart = pos - 1;
        input.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input id="input" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={Remove}>remove</button>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: @DhruvDhing You are welcome! Usually the questioner marks helpful answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which will add reputation to the answerer and himself a bit. It also helps the others to understand that the question has been answered and easily find the answer. But it is not mandatory.